# "The network path was not found" error with multiple backslashes in the error-printed path

Tags: python, windows, path

I am trying to deploy a Flask application on a Windows Server. It works fine on local test but it fails to access the server folders on deployment.
The main folder is a network one which looks like this:

```
mainpath = '//part1//part2/part3/folder'
```

I have a testing route in Flask that just tries to read/print the content of this folder, but it hasn't achieved it so far.

```
os.listdir(mainpath)
```

The error I get is like below:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 53] The network path was not found: '\\\\\\\\part1\\\\part2\\\\part3\\\\folder'
```

Why do Windows add so many backslashes in the path? What is the best practice to avoid this? I have tried more than 30 variances of this but none worked so far. I have tried os.path.normpath, os.path.abspath, Path, PureWindowsPath, different versions of slashes, backslashes, os.path.joins, raw-strings, etc but nothing worked yet

Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried using raw strings? E.g. `r'/your/path/here'`.

Comment: Yes, I tried all variances with raw-strings too (I updated my post to contain this info, thanks